# Fixed effects in a linear probability model (LPM)?

Tags: categorical-data, least-squares, fixed-effects-model, binary-data

I have a dataset with about 6000 obs. in a cross sectional times series structure (countries and years). My dependent/response variable is binary and my independent/explanatory variables are a mix of binary and continuous.

Now, I worry that the explanatory variable I'm interested in might not be independent of unobserved, country-specific, time-invariant factors, so I'd like to remove these with fixed effects (and probably do the same with year-specific, but country-invariant factors).

Since my response variable is binary, I have been using conditional logit models grouped on country, but I find it undesirable for this project that they discard all information on countries without variation on the response variable (there are a lot of those in my sample).

So, I'd like to supplement these with linear probability models (LPM's) with standard fixed effects. However - and here comes my problem - I figure that, besides the usual problems with LPM's, they must have an additional issue in this case since the binary response variable would imply an unnatural restriction on the unobserved effects.

I'm just not sure how big of a problem this restriction is? And if it depends on whether or not the rest of the model violates the 0-1 bound of the response variable?